# New to Laravel PHP framework. Routes other than "/" doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I'm a beginner at Lavarel framework. I know about MVC structure, Since I've used it before inside ASP.net, But using Laravel is quite confusing to me.

I've installed Laravel inside `photozoom` directory using:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel photozoom --prefer-dist
```

Here's my `app/routes.php` :

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'users route is working!';
});
```

When i run `http://localhost/photozoom/public/users`, I get `404 Not Found` error.

But when i try `http://localhost/photozoom/public/`, The route for `/` is invoked and the corresponding view is called.

I even tried to create a view for the `users` route. Using Laravel documentation. I've created two files :

`layout.blade.php` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel Quickstart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Laravel Quickstart</h1>

        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

`users.blade.php` :

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    Users!!!
@stop
```

But still, When i call `http://localhost/photozoom/public/users` I get `404 Not Found error`.

Here's my `public/.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using PHP 5.5, Apache 2.4.6 .

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**SOLVED**
After enabling mod_rewrite, I had to enable `AllowOverride` too.

Comment: What's in your `.htaccess`? Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by "After enabling mod_rewrite, I had to enable AllowOverride too." ? Can you go into detail ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `http://localhost/photozoom/public/index.php/users` for now. And then enable [pretty URLs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls).

Comment: Hmm, adding `index.php` solved it. But how can i enable pretty URLs? I have `mod_rewrite` enabled. But no good. I'll add my `.htacces` in the question.

Comment: IVE BEEN TRYING TO SOLVE THIS FOR 3 DAYS NON STOP!
You are a legend !

Answer (score 7):

The .htaccess file in the /public directory enables pretty URLs.
In order for the .htaccess file to do its work:

- Apache2 must have mod_rewrite enabled (a2enmod rewrite)
- In your Apache configuration you must use the AllowOverride option to
  allow the .htaccess file to 'override' your default Apache2
  configuration.

For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/photozoom/> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two AllowOverride in the httpd.conf file.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

and

```
DocumentRoot "D:/www"
<Directory "D:/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're running windows 10 then you just need to do one thing simple as enough.

create new folder in c:/wamp64/www/ and
copy your all file from laravel folder and paste in folder which you just created thats my solution.